# python json error Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Tags: python, json

Please help

```
def checkActionType(jsondata):
    print("In checkActionType method") 
    print type(jsondata)
    jsonformat = json.loads(jsondata)
    action=str(jsonformat["action"])
```

and i passing

```
data = {u'userId': 3, u'module': u'report', u'clientId': 3, u'action': u'tablestats'}
```

r = checkActionType(data)

Getting an error

```
jsonformat = json.loads(jsondata)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Comment: try this `data = {'userId': 3, 'module': 'report', 'clientId': 3, 'action': 'tablestats'}`

Comment: Thanks i tried this i should have mentioned this in the question, the data is coming from api java how can i remove u from it

Comment: I am getting the same kind of data with u in it

Comment: you have diverted the question into some wrong direction

Comment: Yw , that was your question , i'm not responsible to answer all of your question , i've solved this problem for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You data isn't a valid json which can be converted into dictionary, it's actually a dictinary, `data` **shall be** a valid json string, try to pass data below as a parameter:

```
data = '{"action": "tablestats", "userId": 3, "clientId": 3, "module": "report"}'
```

See more about json in the article ["JSON: What It Is, How It Works, & How to Use It"](https://www.copterlabs.com/json-what-it-is-how-it-works-how-to-use-it/)

Comment: what does these `u`s before each element ?

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi as data is a dict `u` means that it's a unicode key,  see updated code.

Comment: yeah , this is true (Y)

Comment: ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1), Same error

Comment: check your code, it works without errors on OPs code of `checkActionType`

Comment: data i am getting is with u init their should be a way to decode it right

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in two ways :

**1 -** define your data like a json , and pass json to method :

```
def checkActionType(jsondata):
    print("In checkActionType method") 
    print type(jsondata)
    action=str(jsondata["action"])
```

defining data :

```
data = {'userId': 3, 'module': 'report', 'clientId': 3, 'action': 'tablestats'}
```

using it :

```
r = checkActionType(data)
```

**2 -** pass the String instead :

```
def checkActionType(jsondata):
    print("In checkActionType method") 
    print type(jsondata)
    jsonformat = json.loads(jsondata)
    action=str(jsonformat["action"])
```

and pass this data instead :

```
data = "{'userId': 3, 'module': 'report', 'clientId': 3, 'action': 'tablestats'}"
```

call it :

```
r = checkActionType(data)
```

[image]

Comment: action=str(jsondata["action"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
got this error with the first apporach

Comment: so use `action = jsondata["action"]`

Comment: action = jsondata["action"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: which version of python you are using ?

Comment: python 2.7 verson

Comment: `import demjson` and use the above code , i will send it's screenshot , so that you see it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135275/discussion-between-dev-jalla-and-mohsen-fatemi).

Comment: i've tried exact code shown in screenshot , as you can see it works